# Spark-cloudant package 1.6.4 loaded by %AddJar does not get used by notebook

Tags: apache-spark, ibm-cloud, data-science-experience, spark-cloudant

I'm trying to use the latest spark-cloudant package with a notebook:

```
%AddJar -f https://github.com/cloudant-labs/spark-cloudant/releases/download/v1.6.4/cloudant-spark-v1.6.4-167.jar
```

Which outputs:

```
Starting download from https://github.com/cloudant-labs/spark-cloudant/releases/download/v1.6.4/cloudant-spark-v1.6.4-167.jar
Finished download of cloudant-spark-v1.6.4-167.jar
```

Followed by:

```
val dfReader = sqlContext.read.format("com.cloudant.spark")
dfReader.option("cloudant.host", sourceDB.host)
if (sourceDB.username.isDefined && sourceDB.username.get.nonEmpty) dfReader.option("cloudant.username", sourceDB.username.get)
if (sourceDB.password.isDefined && sourceDB.password.get.nonEmpty) dfReader.option("cloudant.password", sourceDB.password.get)
val df = dfReader.load(sourceDB.database).cache()
```

Which outputs:

```
Use connectorVersion=1.6.3, dbName=ratingdb, indexName=null, viewName=null,jsonstore.rdd.partitions=5, + jsonstore.rdd.maxInPartition=-1,jsonstore.rdd.minInPartition=10, jsonstore.rdd.requestTimeout=900000,bulkSize=20, schemaSampleSize=1
```

The connector is 1.6.3. My notebook is:

```
Scala 2.10 with Spark 1.6
```

I've tried restarting the kernel but that didn't help.

Other debug information:

```
Server Information:

You are using Jupyter notebook.

The version of the notebook server is 4.2.0 and is running on:
Python 2.7.11 (default, Jun 24 2016, 12:41:03) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)]

Current Kernel Information:

IBM Spark Kernel
```

---

**Update**

I tried the following:

```
import sys.process._

"test -d ~/data/libs/scala-2.10" #|| "mkdir -p ~/data/libs/scala-2.10" !
"wget -c -O ~/data/libs/scala-2.10/cloudant-spark-v1.6.4-167.jar https://github.com/cloudant-labs/spark-cloudant/releases/download/v1.6.4/cloudant-spark-v1.6.4-167.jar" !
"ls ~/data/libs/scala-2.10/" !

println("Now restart the kernel")
```

Unfortunately, this didn't work - 1.6.3 is still being used.

**Update 2**

It appears that the tilda was not getting resolved to my HOME folder in the above code.

See the answer for the working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the following code from a scala notebook worked for me:

```
import sys.process._

val HOME = sys.env("HOME")
val DESTDIR = s"${HOME}/data/libs/scala-2.10"

s"test -d ${DESTDIR}" #|| s"mkdir -p ${DESTDIR}" !
s"wget -q -c -O ${DESTDIR}/cloudant-spark-v1.6.4-167.jar https://github.com/cloudant-labs/spark-cloudant/releases/download/v1.6.4/cloudant-spark-v1.6.4-167.jar" !
s"ls ${DESTDIR}/" !
```

I have also requested product management for the spark service to officially upgrade this library.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, for DSX Notebooks with Spark, the version 1.6.3 of `cloudant-spark` is supported out of box. That means the jar for this package is provided on the `gpfs` and the path to the jar was added to various environment variables, so that during starting the kernel it will be added to the runtime environment.

When you use the `%AddJar` magic it is possible that it will not work to overload the older version, due to the implementation of the magic and the location of the download path, see https://github.com/ibm-et/spark-kernel/wiki/List-of-Current-Magics-for-the-Spark-Kernel.

The setup of the runtime environment (including for Spark) includes the addition of various jars at different steps, so if you goal is it to use the version 1.6.4 of `spark-cloudant`, you would have to to try to find a location on the gpfs to dump the jar, so that it will be pulled at the right time (some guessing here, because I do not have the full picture on the setup!).

As long term solution, I would suggest that you reach out to the support for the spark service and submit a request to support the new version, so that it will be provided out of box.

As a short term solution (might not work when the setup steps for the runtime environment are changing), you can do the following:

1. Open in your DSX project a Python notebook.
2. Find out your USERID with

   `!whoami`
3. Check your user specific directory for Spark libs with (USERID = output from step 2):

   `!ls /gpfs/fs01/user/USERID/data/libs`

You will notice that the `spark-cloudant` jar is not present there.

4. Dump the newer version of `spark-cloudant` to the user specific directory for Spark libs (USERID = output from step 2):

   `!wget https://github.com/cloudant-labs/spark-cloudant/releases/download/v1.6.4/cloudant-spark-v1.6.4-167.jar -P  /gpfs/fs01/user/USERID/data/libs`
5. Check your user specific directory for Spark libs with (USERID = output from step 2): See step 3

You will notice that `spark-cloudant` jar for version 1.6.4 is present there.

6. Restart the kernel of your Scala notebook and try your code again.

The approach worked for me to patch the version of `spark-cloudant`, however it is a short term and temporally workaround, only!